# How manage URL in android?

Tags: android, security

I am new in Android, my app support multiple languages so, i hit diffrent URL(Due diffrent server use for diffrent language) for Diffrent language to get data. So, i want to give URL in string.xml so they call according to Locale specification. Is it Possible? if Yes How much Secure this one.

Comment: `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();` used to get the selected locale of the device. based on this you can create logic to use proper url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `strings.xml` to provide different string resources (such as URLs) for different locales. You'd use the locale postfix for the values folder to do so, such as `values-en` and `values-de`.

In order to access it programmatically, you would then execute:

```
String url = context.getString( R.string.id_of_url_string );
```

`context` can be your application context, activity, etc...